# How to navigate to a section tag # when opening a URL with Python's webbrowser?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-webbrowser

When using Python's `webbrowser.open(local_webpage_url#section)` the `#section` tag at the end of the `local_webpage_url` gets ignored and the browser opens the HTML page but does not navigate to the section. (The address bar also does not show the `#section`)

Is there special syntax or an additional navigation command that can be used to navigate to the section without using any additional modules?

**SMALL UPDATE**

I am linking to Sphinx documentation anchors, so that the user gets directed to the relevant section. I tried Georgy's method and the url he has worked for me as well, but my local url is just directing to the page, not the anchor.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. The following works fine for me: `webbrowser.open('https://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open', new=2)`

Comment: Maybe the anchors are generated dynamically?

Comment: I am linking to Sphinx documentation anchors, so that the user gets directed to the relevant section. I tried Georgy's method and the url he has worked for me as well, but my local url is just directing to the page, not the anchor.

Comment: I think you should add this info to your post, and add the tag for python-sphinx, so that people who work with it will see your question.